# How to access a child-template-variable from the base one? If that's even possible

Tags: python, django, templates, jinja2

I have a base.html template in which i'll include two different headers, but only one of them will show up depending on a variable I want to declare on the child template.

I read on [this jinja page](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/tricks/#highlighting-active-menu-items) that "*because assignments outside of blocks in child templates are global and executed before the layout template is evaluated it’s possible to define the active menu item in the child template*"

So this is what I was hoping to do:

**base.html**:

```
{% if header_type == "header1" %}
    {% include '/header_1.html' %}
{% endif %}

{% if header_type == "header2" %}
    {% include '/header_2.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

And on the header_1.html file I was hoping to set a variable like header_type = "header1". Basically the child-page will tell which header should be rendered, but it seems I'm not able to do that.

I'm not entirely sure this is the best way of achieving this "dynamic header", if anyone has any better suggestion.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the `jinja2` templating engine?

Comment: Yeah, I actually didn't know that. I mean, I thought that any {{ variable }} written like that was being handled by jinja2. Actually this is just the regular Python template language. By the way, I'm validating which header the user is getting by the request.path information. If user's in a page that starts with /something/, it's header1, otherwise header2. Still, it's not good to hardcode URLs like that.

Comment: Also: jinja2 comes by default with Flask, that's the reason behind the misconception.

Comment: There is no "regular Python template language", and you tagged the question Django, not Flask.